# Создание фоновой службы Android

Tags: c#, android, .net, xamarin

Задача состоит в создании фоновой службы на платформе Android. При этом не должно быть вообще никакого UI, кроме постоянного уведомления в трее, информирующего о том, что служба запущена и работает.

- *Проблема 1*: Как полностью убрать UI? Я использую шаблон Blank App и не понимаю что нужно сделать, чтобы окно совсем не отображалось даже при запуске на мгновение. Приложение чисто должно запустить сервис и всё.
- *Проблема 2*: Запуск Foreground сервиса. Это должен быть насколько возможно "неубиваемый" сервис. Сейчас проблема видимо с вызовом `StartForeground` (на моменте регистрации приложение падает.

Содержимое `OnStartCommand`:

```
void CreateNotificationChannel() {

    if (Build.VERSION.SdkInt < BuildVersionCodes.O) return;

    var channel = new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID, channel_name, NotificationImportance.Default) {
        Description = description
    };

    var notificationManager = (NotificationManager)GetSystemService(NotificationService);
    notificationManager.CreateNotificationChannel(channel);
}

[return: GeneratedEnum]
public override StartCommandResult OnStartCommand(Intent intent, [GeneratedEnum] StartCommandFlags flags, int startId) {

    CreateNotificationChannel();
    var builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID)
          .SetContentTitle("Title")
          .SetSmallIcon(Resource.Mipmap.ic_launcher)
          .SetContentText("Content text")
          .SetOngoing(true);

    StartForeground(NOTIF_ID, builder.Build()); // Crash here
    return StartCommandResult.NotSticky;
}
```

Запуск сервиса:

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
    SetContentView(Resource.Layout.activity_main);

    this.StartForegroundServiceCompat<BackgroundService>();
}
```

Метод расширения:

```
public static void StartForegroundServiceCompat<T>(this Context context, Bundle args = null) where T : Service {

    Intent intent = new Intent(context, typeof(T));
    if (args != null) intent.PutExtras(args);

    if (Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= BuildVersionCodes.O) context.StartForegroundService(intent);
    else context.StartService(intent);
}
```

---

С проблемой №2 вроде удалось разобраться. При вызове `StartForeground` вылетало исключение Permission Denial - просто добавил в манифесте необходимое разрешение
`FOREGROUND_SERVICE`. Сервис действительно продолжает работу после закрытия окна приложения. Однако, его можно закрыть через раздел Работающие службы в настройках.

Comment: [Оно](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/app-fundamentals/services/creating-a-service/)? [еще ссылка](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59936690/12888024)

Comment: Это мне не помогло. Нет примеров формирования `Notification` для метода `StartForeground`. Проблема 1 даже не рассматривается где либо.

Comment: Первая ссылка вообще по моему не в тему. Речь не просто о создании и запуске службы, а о Foreground службах.

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/xamarin/android/app-fundamentals/services/foreground-services

Comment: @mik.ov Эта статья и использовалась при написании вопроса. Возможно у вас есть предложения по улучшению кода?